# How to extract separate nth lines from a txt file and assign them to key:value pairs in python 3?

Tags: python

I'm learning how to code and I've run into a problem I don't have an answer to. I have a text file from which I have to make three dictionaries:

```
Georgie Porgie
87%
$$$
Canadian, Pub Food

Queen St. Cafe
82%
$
Malaysian, Thai
```

For the purpose of this thread I just want to ask how to extract the first line of each text block and store it as a key and the second line of each block as a value? I am supposed to write a code using nothing more but the **very** basic functions and loops.

Here is my code(once the file is opened):

```
d = {}
a = 0
for i in file:
    d[i] = i + 1
    a = i + 5
return(d)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please show your own code attempt at this and explain what difficulties you are having in your code. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You need to show your specific problems in your own code in the form of a [mcve]

Comment: Yes, sorry, I added my code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to read the file:

```
with open("data.txt") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
```

The *with* clause ensures it is closed after it is read. Next, according to your description, a line contains a key if the `index % 5` is 0. Then, the next line contains the value. With only "basic" elements of the language, you could construct your dictionary like this:

```
dic = {lines[idx].strip(): lines[idx + 1].strip() 
       for idx in range(0, len(lines), 5)}
```

This is a dictionary comprehension, which can also be written unfolded.

Now you can also zip the keys and values first, so you can iterate them quite easily. This makes the dictionary comprehension more readable. The *strip* method is necessary though, since we want to get rid of the line breaks.

```
entries = zip(lines[::5], lines[1::5])
dic = {key.strip(): value.strip() for key, value in entries}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! The only thing I didn't understand was that dictionary comprehension and how to unfold. Does it mean that it can be written as a separate loop?